# Why is a char and a bool the same size in c++?

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm reading *The C++ Programming Language.* In it Stroustrup states that `sizeof(char) == 1` and `1 <= sizeof(bool)`.  The specifics depend on the implementation.  Why would such a simple value as a boolean take the same space as a char?

Comment: They are not "the same size". Like every other type, a `bool` must be _at least_ the same size as a `char`. But it is free to be larger.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In modern computer architectures, a byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory. To pack multiple bits into a byte requires applying extra bit-shift operations. At the compiler level, it's a trade off of memory vs. speed requirements (and in high-performance software, those extra bit-shift operations can add up and slow down the application needlessly).

Answer (score 23):

Because in C++ you can take the address of a boolean and most machines cannot address individual bits.

Comment: true, but you can fake it by overloading the unary & operator and returning a proxy reference class :-P

Comment: The resulting "fake pointer" would not be representable as a char*, which the C++ standard requires for pointers to built-in types (not including pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member). So while fun for user-defined types, the trick can't be used by the compiler for bool.

Comment: This is the right answer.  A more interesting question is why the authors of the standard weren't willing to recognize the possibility of a standalone 'bit' type whose address couldn't be taken, especially it does recognize the concept of such types within structures (using bitfields), and since such types have been used for a long time been in the embedded C world.  Not all linkers would support granularity finer than one byte, but a standard could allow compilers to allocate 'bit' variables on a per-bit basis when convenient without requiring them to do so in any circumstance.

Answer (score 12):

It takes the same space, because the smallest amount of space you can write in memory is a single byte.  Both values are stored in a byte.  Although you theoretically only need 1 bit to signify a boolean value, you still have to have a whole byte to store the value.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically you only need a single bit for a bool, but working with less than 1 byte's worth of data is messy.  You need more instructions to achieve anything and you don't really benefit.

If you want to pack multiple booleans into a single byte you can use a [bit-field structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

Comment: But you would be better off not doing so.

Answer (score 3):

A byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory.

Consider the following code:

```
    bool b[9];
    bool *pb0 = &b[0];
    bool *pb1 = &b[1];

    for (int counter=0; counter<9; ++counter)
    {
         // some code here to fill b with values
         b[counter] = true;

    }
```

If bool is stored as 1 bit, then pb0 will equal pb1, because both have the same address. This is clearly not desirable!

Additionally the assignment in the loop will result in non-trival assembly code. It will involve a different bit shift in each iteration of the loop. In high-performance software, those extra bit-shift operations can slow down the application needlessly.

The STL library provides a work-around in situations where space DO matter. The use of std::vector<bool> will store bool as 1 bit. The paradox of the example above do not apply because

- the overloading of operator[] hides the rigors of the bit shift operation
- the use of iterators instead of pointers give additional flexibilty to the implementation

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in most implementation that I know of sizeof(bool) == sizeof(int).  "int" is intended to be the data size that is most efficient for the CPU to work with. Hence things which do not have a specific size (like "char") are the same size as an int. If you had a large number of them per object, you may want to implement a means of packing them for storage, but during normal calculation, it should be left it's native size.

Comment: if you are going to use an array of booleans, use the std::vector<bool>, it has specialised implementations for bit vectors that only uses one bit per element.

Comment: @mats: std::bitset is less crazy. vector<bool> tries and fails to be an STL container. There's also boost::dynamic_bitset, which unlike std::bitset can grow.

Answer (score 2):

There is this thing in C++ called vector that attempts to exploit the fact that you can theoretically store 8 bools in one char, but it's widely regarded as a mistake by the C++ standards committee.  The book "effective stl" actually says "don't use it".  That should give you an idea of how tricky it is.

BTW: Knuth has a [book](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc1a.ps.gz) just dedicated to bitwise operations.  Boost also has a [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) dedicated to handling large numbers of bits in a more memory efficient way.

Comment: You mean "called vector **<bool>**". Every other type of `vector` is perfectly sane.