# Why is sizeof(bool) not defined to be one by the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, boolean, standards, sizeof, language-design

Size of `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` is defined to be 1 byte, by the C++ Standard itself. I'm wondering why it didn't define the `sizeof(bool)` also?

C++03 Standard $5.3.3/1 says,

> sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and
>   sizeof(unsigned char) are 1; the
>   result of sizeof applied to **any other**
>   fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-defined. [Note: **in
>   particular,sizeof(bool) and
>   sizeof(wchar_t) are
>   implementation-defined**.69)

I understand the rationale that [sizeof(bool) cannot be less than one byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626815/why-is-a-boolean-1-byte-and-not-1-bit-of-size/4626993#4626993). But is there any rationale why it should be greater than 1 byte either? I'm not saying that implementations define it to be greater than 1, but the Standard left it to be defined by implementation **as if it may be greater than 1.**

If there is no reason `sizeof(bool)` to be greater than 1, then I don't understand why the Standard didn't define it as just `1 byte`, as it has defined `sizeof(char)`, and it's all variants.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is specified to be one, but is it specified to be one byte ? I don't think the exact size is precised, in case an architecture comes out that stores bits by 16 instead of 8.

Comment: @Matthieu: "one byte" is also defined to be the same as a char ;-). If an architecture stores bits by 16, then there are 16 bits in a byte as far as C++ is concerned on that platform. Any belief you may have that "byte" means "octet" must be left at the door...

Comment: @Matthieu: the **unit** of sizeof is *byte*. But byte doesn't necessarily mean 8 bits!

Comment: @Steve, @Nawaz: Ah thanks, didn't remember the distinction :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<cstddef>` or `<stddef.h>`, specifes the number of bits in a byte.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a char and a bool the same size in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266870/why-is-a-char-and-a-bool-the-same-size-in-c)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Many platforms cannot effectively load values smaller than 32 bits. They have to load 32 bits, and use a shift-and-mask operation to extract 8 bits. You wouldn't want this for single `bool`s, but it's OK for strings.

Comment: Many platforms? Such as? If such platforms exist, then do they really define `sizeof(bool)` greater than 1?

Comment: ARM, for one, although it's really the `STRB` (Store Byte) instruction which is funny. _"STRB repeats the bottom 8 bits of the source register four times across the data bus. The external memory system should activate the appropriate byte subsystem to store the data."_

Comment: STRB isn't repeating the same byte over four bus cycles, it repeats it four times over one bus cycle, and the memory controller can slurp the data off any byte lane. It doesn't take any longer than storing a word  with STR.

Comment: please consider your answer is vague (Even your answer is correct), users have to read all other answers to find out what did you say about this question.

Answer (score 32):

The other likely size for it is that of `int`, being the "efficient" integer type for the platform.

On architectures where it makes any difference whether the implementation chooses 1 or `sizeof(int)` there could be a trade-off between size (but if you're happy to waste 7 bits per `bool`, why shouldn't you be happy to waste 31? Use bitfields when size matters) vs. performance (but when is storing and loading bool values going to be a genuine performance issue? Use `int` explicitly when speed matters). So implementation flexibility wins - if for some reason `1` would be atrocious in terms of performance or code size, it can avoid it.

Answer (score 28):

As @MSalters pointed out, some platforms work more efficiently with larger data items.

Many "RISC" CPUs (e.g., MIPS, PowerPC, early versions of the Alpha) have/had a considerably more difficult time working with data smaller than one word, so they do the same. IIRC, with at least some compilers on the Alpha a bool actually occupied 64 bits.

gcc for PowerPC Macs defaulted to using 4 bytes for a bool, but had a switch to change that to one byte if you wanted to.

Even for the x86, there's some advantage to using a 32-bit data item. gcc for the x86 has (or at least used to have -- I haven't looked recently at all) a define in one of its configuration files for `BOOL_TYPE_SIZE` (going from memory, so I could have that name a little wrong) that you could set to 1 or 4, and then re-compile the compiler to get a bool of that size.

As for the reason behind this, I'd say it's a simple reflection of a basic philosophy of C and C++: leave as much room for the implementation to optimize/customize its behavior as reasonable. Require specific behavior only when/if there's an obvious, tangible benefit, and unlikely to be any major liability, especially if the change would make it substantially more difficult to support C++ on some particular platform (though, of course, if the platform is sufficiently obscure, it might get ignored).

Comment: If memory serves, the reason behind it on Mac OS X was that cross-platform OS code had assumed `bool` to be compatible with atomic operations, but PowerPC required higher alignment. There was no time to add the missing `typedef` and no other way to define an interface boundary between differing definitions of `bool`. The older Mac OS (including presumably its GCC port) had 1-byte `bool`, and the switch probably provided compatibility to such code at the expense of no longer being able to use many BSD system calls. Programmers then had to wean from the switch by defining their own `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

The operation resulted in 'sizeof' is MADUs (minimal addresible unit), not bytes. So family processors C54 *. C55 * Texas Instuments, the expression 1 MADU = 2 bytes.

For this platform sizeof (bool) = sizeof (char) = 1 MADUs = 2 bytes.
This does not violate the C + + standard, but clarifies the situation.

Comment: No, the value yielded by `sizeof` is in bytes. The C++ standard defines the word "byte" differently than the way it's commonly used. If the minimum addressible unit is 16 bits, then a byte (as defined by both C and C++) is 16 bits for that platform. `sizeof (char) == 1` by definition; if `sizeof (char)` yields 2, your compiler is non-conforming.

Comment: Reference: ISO C++ 2011 standard, 5.3.3 [expr.sizeof]: "The **`sizeof`** operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand."

Comment: It's worth emphasising what @KeithThompson says here: the C (and C++) standard define `byte` to be `sizeof(char)`, and not the other way round. If you're only a platform where `sizeof(char)` is not 8 bits you will have a very bad time until you realise this.

Comment: I guess you could find out the number of bytes in the usual sense using `CHAR_BIT/8`, however I could not find a rule prescribing that `CHAR_BIT` must be a multiple of 8. Considering the answers above, it very, very likely is on any platfrom, though.