# C++ BOOL (typedef int) vs bool for performance

Tags: c++, performance, typedef, boolean

I read somewhere that using BOOL (typedef int) is better than using the standard c++ type bool because the size of BOOL is 4 bytes (i.e. a multiple of 4) and it saves alignment operations of variables into registers or something along those lines...

Is there any truth to this? I imagine that the compiler would pad the stack frames in order to keep alignments of multiple of 4s even if you use bool (1 byte)?

I'm by no means an expert on the underlying workings of alignments, registers, etc so I apologize in advance if I've got this completely wrong. I hope to be corrected. :)

Cheers!

Comment: If `bool` is faster as 4 bytes, the compiler will make it 4 bytes. It depends on the scenario. So no, `BOOL` does not give a performance benefit.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you can only find out through profiling, but do you want a bool that can have values other than 0,1? Even negative values?

Comment: This will not make any difference. The compiler pads values to ensure that they're properly aligned. Use the type that makes the most sense. If it's a Boolean value, make it a `bool`, not an `int` (or some `typedef` thereof).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, `sizeof(bool)` is not necessarily `1`. It is [implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067492/why-the-sizeofbool-is-not-defined-to-be-one-by-the-standard-itself), giving the compiler writer freedom to choose a size that's suitable for the target platform.

Also, `sizeof(int)` is not necessarily `4`.

There are multiple issues that could affect performance:

- alignment;
- memory bandwidth;
- CPU's ability to efficiently load values that are narrower than the machine word.

What -- if any -- difference that makes to a particular piece of code can only be established by profiling that piece of code.

Comment: And the compiler will probably have adapted the size of a `bool` to reflect these issues.

Comment: Generally speaking though; For the sake of the example say that bool is 1 byte and say that an int is 4 bytes. Say you have a struct{bool x; int y}; Does the x cause y to be miss-aligned because it's size is not a multiple of 4? Or does the compiler pad the addresses so that y is aligned?

Comment: @KarlHansson: Padding is implementation-specific. Implementations that I am familiar with would insert padding after `x` so that `y` is suitably aligned.

Answer (score 2):

The only guaranteed size you can get in C++ is with `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` <sup>2)</sup>, which are always exactly one byte and defined for every platform.<sup>0)</sup><sup>1)</sup>

---

<sup>0) Though a byte does not have a defined size. `sizeof(char)` is always `1 byte`, but might be 40 binary bits in fact</sup>

<sup>1) Yes, there is `uint32_t` and friends, but no, their definition is optional for actual C++ implementations. Use them, but you may get compile time errors if they are not available (compile time errors are always good)</sup>

<sup>2) `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` are distinct types and it is not defined whether `char` is `signed` or not. Keep this in mind when overloading functions and writing templates.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are three commonly accepted performance-driven practices in regards to booleans:

1. In if-statements order of checking the expressions matters and one needs to be careful about them.
2. If a check of a boolean expression causes a lot of branch mispredictions, then it should (if possible) be substituted with a bit twiddling hack.
3. Since boolean is a smallest data type, boolean variables should be declared last in structures and classes, so that padding does not add noticeable holes in the structure memory layout.

I've never heard about any performance gain from substituting a boolean with (unsigned?) integer however.

Comment: #3 isnt necessarily true. In a scenario where there is already a gap in the struct (due to alignment/auto-padding), you can "fill" the gap for "free" by placing the bool there. Lets say this struct so far already has a size which is a perfect multiple of the cache-line size, then adding a bool at the end of the struct (instead of filling the gap) will actually cause a cache miss in some situations when trying to access that bool member, (whereas there would be no cache-miss otherwise). You should judge each struct independently.

Comment: @PreetKukreti you're right, I should have said 'commonly accepted practices not requiring knowledge of underlying platform'. If you know the platform on which SW is to be executed, then yes, you can know the alignment (4 or 8 or ...) and adjust accordingly - fill in holes, align to cache lines, etc. What I suggested in the list were general rules to deal with booleans.