# Example of systems/compilers where sizeof(bool) is higher than 1 (in c++)?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, boolean, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why the sizeof(bool) is not defined to be one, by the Standard itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067492/why-the-sizeofbool-is-not-defined-to-be-one-by-the-standard-itself)

I have tested `sizeof(bool)` on several systems and I've always found `1` (same as `sizeof(char)`). What are the most widespread systems/c++ compilers where `sizeof(bool)` is strictly higher than `1` ?

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067492/why-the-sizeofbool-is-not-defined-to-be-one-by-the-standard-itself has a bunch of examples in the answers.

Comment: Does [Visual 4.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4dy80a.aspx) count?