# CRITICAL_SECTION for set and get single bool value

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, winapi

now writing complicated `class` and felt that I use to much `CRITICAL_SECTION`.

As far as I know there are atomic operations for some types, that are always executed without any hardware or software interrupt.

I want to check if I understand everything correctly.

- To set or get atomic value we don't need `CRITICAL_SECTION` because doing that there won't be interrupts.
- `bool` is atomic.

So there are my statements, want to ask, if they are correct, also if they are correct, what types variables may be also set or get without `CRITICAL_SECTION`?

**P. S.** I'm talking about getting or setting **one single value** per method, not two, not five, but one.

Comment: Whether a type can be read/written/manipulated atomically is very much implementation (and there maybe even compiler option) defined. You should mostly rely on `std::atomic` and friends.

Comment: The only functions I would do this with are the Interlocked functions - e.g. `InterlockedIncrement` etc. [See here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684122(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You are going to get yourself into a *lot* of trouble with this.  Slamming a critical section around a bool doesn't accomplish anything.  And std::atomic<> does *not* magically make a big chunk of code thread-safe.  Thread-safety needs to be built-in from the start, you cannot add it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't need locks round atomic data, but internally they might lock. Note for example, C++11's `std::atomic` has a `is_lock_free` function.
2. `bool` may not be atomic. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624776/can-a-bool-read-write-operation-be-not-atomic-on-x86) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320838/when-do-i-really-need-to-use-atomicbool-instead-of-bool)

Answer (score 4):

**Note: This answer applies to Windows and says nothing of other platforms.**

There are no InterlockedRead or InterlockedWrite functions; simple reads and writes with the correct integer size (and alignment) are atomic on Windows (["Simple reads and writes to properly-aligned 32-bit variables are atomic operations."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

(and there are no cache problems since a properly-aligned variable is always on a single cache line).

However, *reading and modifying* such variables (or any other variable) are not atomic:

- Read a `bool`? Fine. Test-And-Set a `bool`? Better use
  [InterlockedCompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms683560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Overwrite an integer? great! Add to
  it? Critical section.

Comment: In Windows you can use `InterlockedXxx` easily to both set (`InterlockedExchange`) and add (`InterlockedExchangeAdd`).

Comment: You should say what architecture this applies to, I don't think its true on ARM

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/threadprocesssynchronizationapis11_8.html) this can be found:

> Simple reads and writes to properly aligned 64-bit variables are
>   atomic on 64-bit Windows. Reads and writes to 64-bit values are not
>   guaranteed to be atomic on 32-bit Windows. Reads and writes to
>   variables of other sizes are not guaranteed to be atomic on any
>   platform.

Result *should* be correct but in programming it is better not to trust *should*. There still remains small possibility of failure because of CPU cache.

Comment: You forgot the passage about 32-bit variables (previous paragraph).

Comment: @Medinoc First sentence is important too, however the quoted-one is more important, don't think that it is useful to make wide answers, because there are more info that may (or not may) be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot guarantee for all implementations/platforms/compilers that `bool,` or any other type, or most operations, are atomic. So, no, I don't believe your statements are correct. You can retool your logic or use other means of establishing atomicity, but you probably can't get away with just removing `CRITICAL_SECTION` usage if you rely on it.