# Are C/C++ fundamental types atomic?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

Are C/C++ fundamental types, like `int`, `double`, etc., atomic, e.g. threadsafe?

Are they free from data races; that is, if one thread writes to an object of such a type while another thread reads from it, is the behavior well-defined?

If not, does it depend on the compiler or something else?

Comment: Why do you think they should be? I've never worked with a procedural programming language in which variables of fundamental types were atomic.

Comment: http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/

Comment: No, but they **do** decay.

Comment: Do you mean atomic as in "a reader will never see a value with a mix of old and new bytes" (i.e. "tearing")?  Or does "well defined" mean the full sequential-consistency guarantees of `std::atomic`: ordering with respect to *other* loads/stores?  Either way, **the C++ standard doesn't provide either guarantee**, not even for a `char` AFAIK.  On most hardware, the first (`std::atomic<T>::store(val, std::memory_order_relaxed)`) is free up to the size of a register (but that still doesn't make a read-modify-write `++i` free if you want the whole RMW to be atomic).

Comment: Since C/C++ are compiled into machine code, surely it's hardware-dependent as to the behaviour of multiple writes and reads to the same memory location?

Comment: @Doddy: It's a lot better to think about writing code to the C++ standard.  If you start taking the behaviour of the implementation on your dev box as "the way C++ works", you're going to have a Bad Time, either in the future with a new compiler, or in the future when compiling for a different architecture.  E.g. a C++ implementation on AVR needs to do extra work even for an atomic store with relaxed ordering for anything larger than one byte.  http://gcc.godbolt.org/ unfortunately only has g++ 4.5 for AVR, and doesn't have the full set of libraries anyway.

Comment: Anyway, on further reading of the question, and the wording in the standard, this question is apparently asking about the second sense.  And the answer is:  No, of course not.  It that would impose MASSIVE performance penalties for every read-modify-write to be atomic, and to put memory barriers between every memory access.  Like, factor of 5 to 100 slowdown is my guess, depending on what the code is doing and what CPU it's running on.  Maybe even lower than that for functions that mostly read, not write, on a strongly-ordered architecture like x86, or do a lot with locals.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Pretty sure C# guarantees atomic operations for any types 4 bytes or less. I think it's reasonable to think this would be the case. He isn't stating he thinks they should be, simply asking if they are.

Comment: @ChadSchouggins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433772/are-primitive-data-types-in-c-sharp-atomic-thread-safe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRITICAL\_SECTION for set and get single bool value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315433/critical-section-for-set-and-get-single-bool-value)

Comment: @ChristianHackl "_I've never worked with a procedural programming language in which variables of fundamental types were atomic_" Not even Java?

Comment: @curiousguy: Yes, not even Java.

Comment: @PeterCordes, and what about sense 1? Like, having a read operation of a long read two bytes from the previous value and two bytes from the new value? Considering a long fits a word in a 64 bit system (assuming 8 byte long here), would that still be possible, I wonder? I don't know, it feels to me like the compilers should guarantee that. Either case, I'm using an atomic_long to be safe. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcioLucca: ISO C doesn't guarantee it.  Data-race UB is UB, so literally anything can happen, including having it happen to work as you expect some of the time but not all of the time.  e.g. [Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71867102) - on AArch64, `x = 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` compiles to two stores of `0xaaaaaaaa`.  But constants where the two halves are different do happen to get stored with a single 64-bit `str` w. GCC,  See also https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/

Comment: That's a bummer, lol. Anyway, thanks a lot for the quick response @PeterCordes

Comment: @MarcioLucca: Why a bummer?  What did you hope to gain from it that you couldn't with `memory_order_relaxed` for `std::atomic`?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Nothing really, just simplicity, perhaps. If the compiler/standards give you such guarantees, then you (or especially people beginning to learn the language) don't have to think about it and that's a good thing, I claim. Performance-wise, personally, I'm not too concerned for my use case. That being said, like you mentioned, atomic_longs also solve "sense number 2" (i.e. ordering) and I'm assuming there must be a small penalty for that. In my case, again, I don't need that, I'm fine with two threads reading slightly outdated values. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarcioLucca: Lol, even if they'd been free of tearing when loads or stores actually happen, you absolutely *would* have to think about it very hard, to make sure your code was safe.  e.g. data races being UB lets compilers hoist loads out of loops, like `while(!ready) {}` into `if(!ready) while(42){}`.  [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387478).  You only asked about tearing, not stopping the compiler from optimizing variables into registers (let alone memory ordering wrt. other operations), so I didn't mention this earlier.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No, fundamental data types (e.g., `int`, `double`) are not atomic, see [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Instead you can use `std::atomic<int>` or `std::atomic<double>`.

**Note:** `std::atomic` was introduced with C++11 and my understanding is that prior to C++11, the C++ standard didn't recognize the existence of multithreading at all.

---

As pointed out by @Josh, [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) is an atomic boolean type. It is **guaranteed to be lock-free**, unlike the `std::atomic` specializations.

---

The quoted documentation is from: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf. I'm pretty sure the standard is not free and therefore this isn't the final/official version.

#### 1.10 Multi-threaded executions and data races

> 6. Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location (1.7) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.
> 7. The library defines a number of atomic operations (Clause 29) and operations on mutexes (Clause 30) that are specially identified as synchronization operations. These operations play a special role in making assignments in one thread visible to another. A synchronization operation on one or more memory locations is either a consume operation, an acquire operation, a release operation, or both an acquire and release operation. A synchronization operation without an associated memory location is a fence and can be either an acquire fence, a release fence, or both an acquire and release fence. In addition, there are relaxed atomic operations, which are not synchronization operations, and atomic read-modify-write operations, which have special characteristics.

> 23. Two actions are potentially concurrent if
>       
>       (23.1) — they are performed by different threads, or
>       
>       (23.2) — they are unsequenced, and at least one is performed by a signal handler.
>       
>       The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

#### 29.5 Atomic types

> 4. There shall be explicit specializations of the atomic template for the integral types ``char, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`, `char16_`t, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and any other types needed by the typedefs in the header `<cstdint>`. For each integral type integral, the specialization `atomic<integral>` provides additional atomic operations appropriate to integral types. There shall be a specialization `atomic<bool>` which provides the general atomic operations as specified in 29.6.1..

> 6. There shall be pointer partial specializations of the atomic class template. These specializations shall have standard layout, trivial default constructors, and trivial destructors. They shall each support aggregate initialization syntax.

#### 29.7 Flag type and operations

> 2. Operations on an object of type atomic_flag shall be lock-free. [ Note: Hence the operations should also be address-free. No other type requires lock-free operations, so the atomic_flag type is the minimum hardware-implemented type needed to conform to this International standard. The remaining types can be emulated with atomic_flag, though with less than ideal properties. — end note ]

Comment: *Objects of atomic types are the only C++ objects that are free from data races*. Really? How about `std::mutex` then? (Playing devil's advocate here, it's just that that sentence needs a bit of love and some reference into the Standard.)

Comment: @peppe Those aren't my own words. They are just a snippet from the linked documentation. I don't have a copy of the standard.

Comment: That documentation is then wrong. It's a community wiki which sums up some concepts; in this case it's a bit too approximative and skims over the fact that there are many other data types != `std::atomic` which are free from data races. Only the Standard is the Voice of The One True ^W^W^W^W the reference here.

Comment: @peppe The [C++14 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) states:  **1.10 Multi-threaded executions and data races** ... The execution of a program contains a
*data race*
if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions,
at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal
handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I know. However the sentence "are the only C++ objects" is wrong. They're not. Counterexample: §30.4.1.2.5 [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]: "The implementation shall provide lock and unlock operations, as described below. For purposes of determining the existence of a data race, these behave as atomic operations (1.10)". (Again, I was playing devil's advocate and asking for a more formal answer, not a c&p from a summary on a random wiki.)

Comment: @peppe I've updated the answer to try and address your concerns.

Comment: @pepe It's a technicality, really.  "Data race" is a term which is defined very specifically in the spec, dealing with the reading and writing of values in memory when more than one thread can access the data at the same time.  Mutexes can protect objects from data races, by preventing more than one thread from accessing them, but thats different from making those types data race free.  Meanwhile, the mutex function calls are just that, function calls.  They are not data accesses, so they are not subject to the concept of data races (unless you destroy a mutex which locking it)

Comment: And as for the specific quote you gave, what they are doing is promoting a behavior which does not actually fit into the "data race" category into acting as though they had data races because that was the easiest wording to describe how mutexes and atomics interact.  Do not that they do not say "lock and unlock are data race free" it says you may treat them as though they are atomic operations for purposes of identifying data races.

Comment: @CortAmmon: I was not talking at all about mutexes to protect against data races. I was talking about the fact that **atomic types are not the only data race-free types**; for instance, locking mutexes is a data race-free operation. So I wanted the answer to be modified to quote the Standard about data races, the fact that they're guaranteed not to happen only on conflicting modifications of atomic objects *and* of a number of other types (`mutex`, its companions, etc.); and notably, the primitive types are not amongst these, so they're not safe.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: for reference, you can download the current working draft of the standard for free on https://isocpp.org/ (link to Github on the left side).

Comment: Why did everyone fail to mention that in reality, the only type which is guaranteed, by the C++11 standard, to be atomic is called std::atomic_flag? N3337( §29.7.2)

Comment: @Josh Thank you, I wasn't aware of this type and have updated the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Since C is also (currently) mentioned in the question despite not being in the tags, the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> **5.1.2.3 Program execution**
>
> ...
>
> When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt
>   of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic
>   objects nor of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` are unspecified, as is the
>   state of the floating-point environment. The value of any object
>   modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor
>   of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` becomes indeterminate when the handler
>   exits, as does the state of the floating-point environment if it is
>   modified by the handler and not restored to its original state.

and

> **5.1.2.4  Multi-threaded executions and data races**
>
> ...
>
> Two expression  evaluations
>   *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.
>
> [several pages of standards - some paragraphs explicitly addressing atomic types]
>
> The execution of a program contains a
>   *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens
>   before the other.  **Any such data race results in undefined behavior.**

Note that values are "indeterminate" if a signal interrupts processing, and simultaneous access to types that are not explicitly atomic is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that C11 adds the `_Atomic` type qualifier and the `<stdatomic.h>` header...

Comment: ISO WG14 (C) and WG21 (C++) coordinated to make sure their memory models are similar. That makes it OK to have both the C and C++ tags here. Don't assume that applies to other questions, though !

Comment: AIUI The guarantees on sig_atomic_t only apply to signal interrupts, not threads or shared memory.

Answer (score 12):

## What is atomic?

Atomic, as describing something with the property of an atom. The word atom originates from Latin [atomus](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/atom?s=t) meaning "undivided".

Typically I think of an atomic operation (regardless of language) to have two qualities:

#### An atomic operation is always undivided.

I.e. it is performed in an indivisible way, I believe this is what OP refers to as "threadsafe". In a sense the operation happens instantaneously when viewed by another thread.

For example the following operation is likely divided (compiler/hardware dependent):

```
i += 1;
```

because it can be observed by another thread (on hypothetical hardware and compiler) as:

```
load r1, i;
addi r1, #1;
store i, r1;
```

Two threads doing the above operation `i += 1` without appropriate synchronization may produce the wrong result. Say `i=0` initially, thread `T1` loads `T1.r1 = 0`, and the thread `T2` loads `t2.r1 = 0`. Both threads increment their respective `r1`s by 1 and then store the result to `i`. Although two increments have been performed, the value of `i` is still only 1 because the increment operation was divisible. Note that had there been synchronization before and after `i+=1` the other thread would have waited until the operation was complete and thus would have observed an undivided operation.

Note that even a simple write may or may not be undivided:

```
i = 3;

store i, #3;
```

depending on the compiler and hardware. For example if the address of `i` is not aligned suitably, then an unaligned load/store has to be used which is executed by the CPU as several smaller loads/stores.

#### An atomic operation has guaranteed memory ordering semantics.

Non atomic operations may be re-ordered and may not necessarily occur in the order written in the program source code.

For example, under the ["as-if" rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) the compiler is allowed to re-order stores and loads as it sees fit as long as all access to volatile memory occurs in the order specified by the program "as if" the program was evaluated according to the wording in the standard. Thus non-atomic operations may be re-arranged breaking any assumptions about execution order in a multi-threaded program. This is why a seemingly innocent use of a raw `int` as a signaling variable in multi-threaded programming is broken, even if writes and reads may be indivisible, the ordering may break the program depending on the compiler. An atomic operation enforces ordering of the operations around it depending on what memory semantics are specified. See [`std::memory_order`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

The CPU may also re-order your memory accesses under the memory ordering constraints of that CPU. You can find the memory ordering constraints for the x86 architecture in the [Intel 64 and IA32 Architectures Software Developer Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) section 8.2 starting at page 2212.

## Primitive types (`int`, `char` etc) are not Atomic

Because even if they under certain conditions may have indivisible store and load instructions or possibly even some arithmetic instructions, they do not guarantee the ordering of stores and loads. As such they are unsafe to use in multi-threaded contexts without proper synchronization to guarantee that the memory state observed by other threads is what you think it is at that point in time.

I hope this explains *why* primitive types are not atomic.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sure, the _caches_ are coherent; it's the store buffers that aren't. Even on x86 - see for instance examples 8-3 and 8-5 in chapter 8.2 of the System Programming Guide. Granted it's hardly the wild west of memory ordering like Alpha or POWER, but to say all cores always read the same values at _all_ times is still strictly false per the architecture.

Comment: @Notlikethat Of course a core won't see a store before that store happens. But there is no "brief moment when the caches of the cores are de-synched". That's just nonsense.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz True that that exact wording is erroneous, but the point is there _is_ a period after a write by one core where a read _by a different core_ can still get the old value ("after" in the sense that a read by that first core will return the new value). So the store has both happened and not happened, depending on where you observe from. I'll just point at [page 2217 of this](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) and shut up now ;)

Comment: @Notlikethat Either you're trying to accurately explain how actual hardware works or you aren't. If you are, then you failed, since this has nothing to do with the caches. If you aren't, then this is all needless complication and you'd do much better to talk about the standards. This may seem like needless nitpicking, but I've had to correct this kind of misinformation literally hundreds of times when it becomes a source of misinformation cited by other people who misunderstand how the actual hardware works.

Comment: Re: the fact that coherent caches are a feature of all real-world CPUs that we run C++ threads across: [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) (never, but it works in practice sort of like mo_relaxed because of coherent caches.  In the bad old days before C++11, that's how lock-free code hand-rolled their own atomics, so mainstream compilers did at least de-facto support this.)

Answer (score 6):

An additional info I haven't seen mentioned in the other answers so far:

If you use `std::atomic<bool>`, for example, and `bool` is actually atomic on the target architecture, then the compiler will not generate any redundant fences or locks. The same code would be generated as for a plain `bool`.

In other words, using `std::atomic` only makes the code less efficient if it is actually required to for correctness on the platform. So there is no reason to avoid it.