# Declaring and starting a c++11 thread outside of main

Tags: c++11, c++14

I have a cpp file ("Plugin.cpp") which contains a small plugin that eventually gets linked into a much larger c++11 server project as a shared library.

It needs to start a thread and out of lazyness (it's a quick prototype) I simply declared and started it like so within Plugin.cpp:

```
#include <thread>

bool threadDone = false;

void myFunction() {
    while(!threadDone) {
    }
    // do stuff
}

std::thread myThread = std::thread(&myFunction);

// Called by server to stop tell plugin to cleanup.
void stopPlugin() {
    threadDone = true;
    myThreadDone.join();
    // ....
}
```

It seems like quite the anti-pattern to go starting threads as if the cpp file were a script file, but it works and doesn't seem to cause any problems when I run this code within the larger server project.

Without getting into the details of the larger project:

*Can someone please detail what bad un-intended consequences may arise from doing this, as opposed to starting the thread in a more controlled manner from within an object or function?*

My apologies if this is too obvious, I have not found this answer online and I have not coded in c++ recently so I am quite rusty. But it seems to me that something should eventually go very wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have used an `std::atomic<bool>` instead of a `bool threadDone`. See [When do I really need to use atomic<bool> instead of bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320838/when-do-i-really-need-to-use-atomicbool-instead-of-bool/16321311) for more details.

The way you are declaring your `std::thread` object, you do not have any direct control on at what point the thread is going to start. Is there a pressing need to declare the thread object this way? Another important consideration is if your shared library is loaded/linked against a separate target than the intended server, would it not spawn an additional unintended thread?

If you have a `stopPlugin` method which the server can call to stop the thread, you can always write a `startPlugin` method as well with the actual thread object nicely wrapped in a simple interface like below.

```
class Plugin {
public:
    void startPlugin();
    void stopPlugin();
private:
    std::thread myThread;
};
```

I very rarely use static storage the way you are using it even for much simpler structs and tend to prefer [construct on first use](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Construct_On_First_Use) idiom.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your example.

### `threadDone` is shared data with a data race

`threadDone` is shared data (write from main thread, read from plugin thread). In your example there is no synchronization mechanism (such as [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) or [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)). Hence there is a **data race** in your example; yielding **undefined behavior**.

When dealing with threads in C++ you should know [what the C++ memory model says about threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races).

You can easily verify that the code is not thread safe by [inspecting the assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/UChYeN) of the following code:

```
namespace buggy {

bool threadDone = false;
unsigned turn = 0u;

void myFunction() {
    while(!threadDone) {
        ++turn;
    }
}

}// buggy
```

which reads

```
buggy::myFunction():
        cmp     BYTE PTR buggy::threadDone[rip], 0
        jne     .L1
.L3:
        jmp     .L3
.L1:
        ret
```

Note that `threadDone` is compared exactly once. If it is false then there is an infinite loop (without any increment).

The easiest way to fix the above is given by the use of atomics:

```
#include <atomic>

namespace fixed {

std::atomic<bool> threadDone{false};
std::atomic<unsigned> turn{0u};

void myFunction() {
    while(!threadDone.load()) {
        turn.fetch_add(1u);
    }
}

}// fixed
```

which yields the assembly

```
fixed::myFunction():
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR fixed::threadDone[rip]
        test    al, al
        jne     .L5
.L8:
        lock add        DWORD PTR fixed::turn[rip], 1
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR fixed::threadDone[rip]
        test    al, al
        je      .L8
.L5:
        ret
```

### Initialization order

I expect that the thread from your plugin uses global data as input and output. It is difficult to ensure that the data is properly initialized before use.

### Lack of `startPlugin`, and `stopPlugin` may fail

This is just a note that the interface is asymmetric (`startPlugin` not available because the plugin always starts --- when?). In addition, `stopPlugin` fails if the thread is not `joinable` (e.g., if `stopPlugin` is called twice).

The latter may be a real issue or not.