# Why is there assert( sizeof( bool ) == 1 ) in Doom 3 source?

Tags: c++, assert, sizeof

[Here's the assert](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3/blob/master/neo/idlib/Lib.cpp#L59). In what reasonable circumstances can it fail, and why is the game checking it?

Comment: I am guessing that failure depends on the compiler. It does seem strange.

Comment: What reasonable circumstances? There are implementations where `bool` is the same size as an `int`.

Comment: The standard doesn't guarantee this to be true. I guess they check it because some other code might depend on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/4897844/318716.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman hm, I assumed that in only will be false in very strange cases. (Was obviously wrong, it seems).

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/5067492/318716

Comment: @JosephQuinsey thanks for the link! It's very useful, but I don't think that it's technically a duplicate — since my question is Doom3-specific, there can be some Doom3-specific details, theoretically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some platforms define `bool` to be the same size as `int`. At least older versions of Mac OS X (and likely other RISC BSD ports) were like this. Presumably the code uses `bool` arrays with an assumption of efficiency. Doom has been ported to a lot of platforms so it's probably very cagey about such things.

It has to be done at runtime because there is no standard macro specifying `sizeof(bool)`, and compile time checks didn't work with non-macro expressions until C++11.

Comment: Thanks! But why does it rely on the bool's size?

Comment: @golergka If it's creating very large arrays, then substituting `int` for `char` will cause a bloated memory requirement and hurt performance. Not to mention the possibility of throwing off address arithmetic which may be strictly noncompliant to the standard.

Comment: "Some platforms define bool to be an int" - bool is an inbuilt type and never "defined" to be anything else, though the size of a bool may be the same as that of an int.

Comment: "t has to be done at runtime" appears to be incorrect. E.g., in C++98 you could just `typedef char static_assert_goodbool[(sizeof(bool)==1)? 1 : -1]`. I write "appears to" because maybe you're referring to some internal Doom-specific thing?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Eh, yes, there is that, but it's fair to say there is no *facility* for compile time checks on non-macros. The runtime check is more reasonable in C++03 than it would be in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have come across the the answer you were looking for. Doom 3 is cross platform and on x86 platforms bool is defined by gcc with a size of 1. In gcc(compiler used by Apple at the time),on Mac OS X PowerPC on the other hand it defaults to 4. Use the -mone-byte-bool to change it to 1.

From http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++

> ```
>   -mone-byte-bool
>        Override the defaults for "bool" so that "sizeof(bool)==1".  By
>        default "sizeof(bool)" is 4 when compiling for Darwin/PowerPC and 1
>        when compiling for Darwin/x86, so this option has no effect on x86.
>
>        Warning: The -mone-byte-bool switch causes GCC to generate code
>        that is not binary compatible with code generated without that
>        switch.  Using this switch may require recompiling all other
>        modules in a program, including system libraries.  Use this switch
>        to conform to a non-default data model.
> ```