# Why more memory is assigned to a local variable in stack than required in C++?

Tags: c++, c, memory, gcc, memory-management

I was reading about buffer overflow. I found one strange thing about memory assignment of local variable on stack

```
int f1 ()
{
    char string1[12];
    char string2[4];
}
```

Here allocation is happening on the stack.

Now, In **GCC** string2 is allocated 4 bytes but if I declare other than power of 2 (upto 16)then it is allocated 16 bytes by the compiler. That means if I allocate string2 in 3,5,6,7,....,15 bytes then it is allocated 16 bytes by the compiler but if I allocate in power of 2 like 1,2,4,8... then it is allocated the exact same size. If I assign above 16 bytes (not power of 2) then it allocates 32 bytes (I guess upto 32 bytes).

Whereas in Visual Studio, If I allocate 1 byte then 9 bytes gets allocated, if from 2-4 bytes then 12 bytes gets allocated, if from 5-8 bytes then 16 bytes gets allocated by the compiler.

Anyone know why this kind of assignment???

Atleast In Visual studio, if there is buffer overflow I get a debug error but in gcc nothing happens. GCC only provides segmentation fault only if too large overflow happens.

Comment: Surely the compiler has its reasons. Think about alignment, for instance. As far as the language standards are concerned, this is a non-issue, since you *are* getting all the memory you need.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you measure the memory usage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the compiler allocate more than needed in the stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770751/why-does-the-compiler-allocate-more-than-needed-in-the-stack)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stack frame sizes are affected by memory alignment choices, usually a multiple of 4 for 32-bit code and a multiple of 8 for 64-bit code.

Both compilers can include stack frame corruption checking with a *canary*, an extra 32-bit value at the top of the stack that is initialized at function entry and checked at function exit.  If the canary value changed then a program abort occurs because the stack frame is likely to be corrupted, possibly by malicious code, that can alter the function return address and get it to return to an arbitrary location.  A very popular malware injection vector.

MSVC has the /RTC option, enabled by default in the Debug configuration.  Which adds these canaries in between every local variable.  So it can detect buffer overflow problems on each individual variable.

These canaries of course take extra space, affecting the stack frame size.

Comment: Then, I guess, its better to use more of heap memory then stack memory, if I want an optimal utilization of the memory

Answer (score 6):

Thats due to [**memory-aligment**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). 
Its easier for the CPU to access to memory addresses which are multiples of the size of the data requested.
So the compiler fills your structure with clear bytes to align the structure. For example:

```
struct foo
{
    char a
    int b , c;
    short d;
    bool e;
    double f;
};
```

In theory the size of that struct is (Supposing the size of `bool` is 1 byte, `char`1 byte, `int` 4 bytes, `short` 2 bytes, `double` 8 bytes) 20 bytes. But in practice, the compiler adds "holes" to the struct to align the memory:

```
         0 | 1 | 2 | 3
-----------+---+---+---
0x0000 | a |   |   |
-----------+---+---+---
0x0004 | b | b | b | b
-----------+---+---+---
0x0008 | c | c | c | c
-----------+---+---+---
0x000C | d | d |   |
-----------+---+---+---
0x0010 | e |   |   |
-----------+---+---+---
0x0014 | f | f | f | f
-----------+---+---+---
0x0018 | f | f | f | f
-------+---+---+---+---
```

Comment: The compiler cannot re-order data members (of the same access control level) inside a class. The standard guarantees they will reside on increasing addresses in order of declaration.

Comment: @Angew thanks, I havent considered that. On the other hand, that implies the compiler is not capable of "shrink" the layout in any way?

Comment: Pretty much, unless you use something like `#pragma pack` to prevent padding.

Comment: All true, but the question was about the stack. The compiler may reorder the stack. (or even use different stacks for different variables, if it feels so inclined)

Answer (score 0):

I remember the reason for this is optimization and maybe due to address the size. Another example like this is the boolean type which usually consume 8 bits and could be just one. This can vary a lot from the different compilers. You can find more about the boolean in [Why is a char and a bool the same size in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266870/why-is-a-char-and-a-bool-the-same-size-in-c)